# C++: How much performance impact can programming an input validation function have versus inlining it each time?

Tags: c++, performance, validation

Maybe a simple question, but if I'm writing a decently large amount of code in which the user is continuously inputting data, and I'm constantly validating this data, is there any efficiency advantage or disadvantage to delegating input validation to a specific function? Obviously it's going to be better to look at and understand, but I'm speaking strictly optimization.

For example, if the user is inputting an int, this can be pretty easily done. But what if they're also inputting floats or doubles? Would it still be advantageous to split this in three different validation functions or even to template one function for all three? Or is the difference maybe all so small that it hardly matters at all?

As an example, here's the simplest integer validation. It's used roughly four times in my current project, but I've had others where I'm using it upwards of 10+ times.

```
    bool loopFlag = true;
    int choice = 0;

    do
    {
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (std::cin.fail() || restChoice > NUMHFCS || restChoice <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid choice. Number must be between 1 and 8." 
            << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        }
        else
        {
            loopFlag = false;
        }
    }
    while (loopFlag);
```

Comment: Unless the input is automated and that needs to be validated, it's always going to be the human that's the performance issue, not the code.

Comment: Also, the C++ iostream library is not intended to be used interactively. As its name suggests, its a library for reading streams, not human user input.

Comment: But seriously, writing yourself a library of common input routines can save you a tonne of repeated code and programming and debugging time. Probably worth the time invested.

Comment: 50 separate copies of similar code.  Discover a logic error.  Have fun!  Or: 10 library functions, a bug in one, fix it, QA, done.  Maintenance for the inline version is a nightmare.

Comment: Play around with templates a bit and that 10 library functions can probably be two or three.

Comment: As with all *optimization* questions, don't try to optimize anything until you have an actual profiler output that says the code is a bottleneck. Also, any code that deals primarily with validating user input is going to be limited by the user, not by the code. Profile, get actual data that indicates a bottleneck in code, and then and only then start worrying about how to optimize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't try to inline it yourself. The performance benefit is negligible.** You might get even worse performance: you'll get a bigger binary, which means that there'll be more cache misses when the CPU loads code.

**Reason 1: The compiler knows best.** Here's a handy rule of thumb: **If a function is worth inlining, the compiler will inline it.** Functions that are bigger or more expensive are less likely to get inlined, **and that's ok.** If inlining a function only makes it 0.05% faster, why inline it?

**Reason 2: not inlining big functions can make code faster.** This seems a bit counter-intuitive, but consider this: the smaller the program, the more likely it is that you can fit the most-used parts in the CPU's cache. For big programs, loading code into the cache before running it may slow things down. By packaging things into functions, you make the resulting machine code smaller, and therefore *more likely to fit in the cache.*

**Reason 3: The speedup is negligible.** The example code that you provided is relatively expensive. Input/Output operations are generally pretty expensive, and `std::istream&` uses a lot of virtual functions (which themselves are relatively expensive to call). And the slowest part? **You're asking input from a human.** Asking a human for input is (quite literally) a couple billion times slower than making a function call.

**Reason 4: fixing bugs is a lot harder if you manually inline stuff.** Let's say you discover a mistake in one of the validation functions. If you wrote it as a function, it's easy to fix: change the function, and you're done. But if you inlined the code, fixing it becomes a lot harder. You'll have to find all the places you used that validation code, and fix it individually in each section.